# Important Salesforce documentation missing regarding Lightning Knowledge

Tags: articles, lightning-knowledge

As per the Salesforce,

> Enabling Lightning Knowledge changes your Org's Data Model to use Record Types rather than Article Types. Orgs with multiple articles types require data migration to consolidate article types before enabling Lightning Knowledge.

Which is, if we want to Enable Lightning Knowledge we have to make sure that there is only 1 Article Type.

Now, I've read almost all documentation regarding Lightning Knowledge. It doesn't say anywhere that whenever we Enable the Lightning Knowledge, the Lightning Knowledge object name is same as the Article Type.

Did I miss something in documentation even after going through the documentation multiple time? Or, it's that *obvious* that they didn't put it that in any documentation?

TIA, be gentle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 Weeks of conversations with Salesforce Support, they confirmed that there is No official documentation regarding this. But additionally they have confirmed the below behavior:

The name the Object depends if the Organisation has Salesforce Classic Knowledge Article Type or not. Below are the cases:

**Case 1:** If there are no Salesforce Classic Knowledge Article Types.
In this case, the name of Lightning Knowledge Object will be "Knowledge".

**Case 2:** If there is one Salesforce Classic Knowledge Article Type.
In this case, the name of the Lightning Knowledge Object will be the same as the Salesforce Classic Knowledge Article Type. For example, if Article Type was 'FAQ' then Lightning Knowledge Object type will be 'FAQ__kav'.

Also, below are words from Salesforce Support:

> As of the moment, I was able to confirm that the information and behavior you mentioned was right. Apparently, I don't see any public documentation yet about this behavior, but I will make sure to feedback this article to add what we have observed.

I hope this helps anyone reading this.

-K